# Using a RecyclerView with a Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I want if the user **checked** or **unchecked** to make a message display and add it to the database or to delete it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MachineHolder holder, int position) {

    final MachinelistResponse MachineList = mData.get(position);
    holder.setNameM(MachineList.getName());
    holder.setSerialNumber(MachineList.getSerialNumber());

    MachineDB mydb = new MachineDB(Context);
    boolean Exist =mydb.isExist(MachineList.getSerialNumber());
    if (Exist== true) {
        holder.Checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.Checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }

    holder.Checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    holder.Checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Toast.makeText(Context, "Select", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I can do it in onCheckedChanged() with value of isChecked variable, so what is your issue ?

Comment: First you add "isChecked" variable in your model class. Then Just replace image with Checkbox. Thwn when you ckick on image you update isChecked variable and at that time you also add entry in local database. And when you click second time on image you remove entry from database and update isChecked value.